# Is it possible to use Wingdings in an MSI with Wix?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wingdings

I am trying to use Wingdings in my Wix installer, specifically the characters at 0xFB and 0xFC. I tried unicode variants of these (✗, ✓), but since Wix/MSI requires a specific codepage, these do not work.

My TextStyle is:`<TextStyle Id="Wingdings_Font_Normal" FaceName="Wingdings" Size="8" />`

My control is: `<Control Id="TestResult_Success" Type="Text" X="140" Y="237" Width="24" Height="24" Text="{\Wingding_Font_Normal}ü">`

In my UI, a raw `ü` is rendered, rather than the Wingdings glyph for that character.

Is there some way to get Wingdings working with Wix/MSI?

EDIT:

After having a peek with Orca inside my compiled MSI, I've found that my TextStyle table is being generated correctly:

[image: FontStyle Table from installer]

And the relevant lines of the control table:
[image: Control Table from installer]

I manually added a new TextStyle and changed the Text to use the new TextStyle, but was unable to get any Winding symbols to appear in my installer.

Comment: How does the control table look like?  Can you massage the text in Orca and get a symbol to appear?  If you can, try using Dark to reverse that back to XML and see what it looks like.

Comment: I was not able to use Orca to get any symbols to appear. I'll have a look with Dark next.

Comment: The xml out of Dark looks the same as what I have in my source files, I.E. what I posted

Comment: FWIW, If it can't be done in Orca, it can't be done in WiX.

Comment: I figured that. Could it be environment related? I am on Windows 8.1.

Comment: I doubt it. MSI hasn't changed in years. I would suggest looking at using bitmaps or maybe try a richtext control. I can tell you what an installer unit is ( 1/12 of the height of a 10 point MS Sans Serif font)  but even this one is beyond me. I'm pretty sure MSI simply doesn't support Unicode because Windows 95 didn't support unicode but I don't know where that's written.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a citation to share but I'm 99.9% certain the answer is no.  Windows Installer native/internal UI is about 16 years old and limited in numerous ways.  To create a better UI experience you'd need to provide an external UI handler using a tool such as WiX Burn. This is how WiX provides it's enhanced UI experience.   If you don't mind taking a dependency on .NET 3.0+ (which was included in Windows Vista and beyond by default ) you could go as far as use WPF to do the UI work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by doing the following:

Create a new entry in the TextStyle table, like this for example:

[image: TextStyle table]

After this you can reference to the new TextStyle in the Control Table (column "Text") just like this: `{\WixUI_Font_Wingdings}YourAwesomeText`

Comment: I assume you want to create a check mark (Wingdings: ü) which worked fine for me using this way.

Comment: Can you show this in wxs xml rather then raw MSI table data?  Maybe a screen shot showing the result?  It'd be really interesting to see.

Comment: It would be interesting to see this in the xml. I'll mess around with Orca and see what the table looks like in my non-working version

Comment: The TextStyle table of my compiled MSI has the rows I'd expect for my TextStyle:

Wingdings_Font_Normal, Wingdings, 8, null, null

Comment: What does the text in the Control table look like?